# Java Linux ServerSocket does not do much

Tags: java, linux

I am running Linux Fedora 18 and all I want is my java code to print hello linux in a web browser I type in http:// myhostname. I have use my code in windows and it work find. However in Linux I use port 80 got a permission denied. So I then I use port 8080 no permission denied but it didn't work. Using port 80 the client dose accept and I can send and receive information only on machine the seversocket not on a different even if it is connect ton the network.Last thing I have made policy file to allow port 80 to work but it was useless and I still not sure I to set a policy file in my code. Sorry if this long question but I have been researching this issue for a month not so please don't tell me to google it. So I guess my main question why can't the serverSocket broadcast anything out of the linux machine and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like the user you're using to run your Java application doesn't have enough privileges to use port 80 **or** this port is already used by another application (similar can happen with port 8080).

Comment: "It didn't work" isn't nearly enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list, provide a short but complete demonstrating the problem, and explain how you *see* the problem. (Do you get an exception? What does the web browser show, etc?)

Comment: Mybe having a look here will explain a few things: http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user
But you should separate / split your problems and try to solve them one by one.

Comment: Jon Skeet you should truly read a question first because if you actually take the time to think about it I did follow. Matthias it one problem that no have answer this question to and it will be seen over,over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a yum update and the code work just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you need to be root to use system ports from 0 to 1023.  Tomcat has ways of opening port 80 without leaving the process running as root, but they are a bit complicated to discuss here.  Linux provides ways to give permissions to access these port, but usually I just use port 8080.

If you use port 8080, you need to redirect this using your router to port 80, or you will have to specify that you want to connect to port 8080.  Your browser only assumes port 80. e.g. `http://yourhost:8080/`

To connect to this server from another machine, your firewalls have to be setup so you connect to it all. A firewall is designed to stop traffic you haven't  explicitly allowed. This means you may need to open your firewall on your server, and you network router and put the your public IP address (not your internal one) in the hosts file of your client.

Comment: Thank you but I have tried all of that.

Comment: In that case you will need to test each step of the way that you can access the service to determine why you cannot access it remotely.  I would start by determining where you can access it first.